# Jquery Javascript .each loop up to 100

Tags: jquery, each

I have a little program to add inputs in a div and it works fine the problem is when the .each function iterate mora than 100.

.each function just stop in the 100

Is there any way to .each function does not stop?

```
$(function(){ 

        var myArray = [];
        valores = myArray

        puntos = 5

        $('.generar').click(function(){
            myArray = [];
            //event.preventDefault();
            $('input[name="valores"]').each(function(){
            myArray.push(this.value);
            console.log(myArray);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////   
            datos_c = $( "form" ).serializeArray();
            //console.log( datos_c );
            //alert($( "form" ).serializeArray());
            datos_c.push(valores);              

            });



        });



    $('.agregar_puntos').click(function(){
        valor = $('.datos_informe span:last').text();
        valor2 = parseInt(valor);
        valor3 = valor2+1;
        $('.datos_informe').append("<div class=\"datos_informe_tablas\"><span>"+valor3+"</span>         <input type=\"number\" name=\"valores\">            <input type=\"number\" name=\"valores\">            <input type=\"number\" name=\"valores\">            <input type=\"number\" name=\"valores\">            <input type=\"number\" name=\"valores\">        </div>");

        puntos = puntos + 1


    }); 

    $('.eliminar_puntos').click(function(){
        console.log(puntos);
        if (puntos > 5){
        puntos = puntos -1
        }

        $(".datos_informe_tablas:eq("+puntos+")").remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `$n.each()` does not stop at 100 iterations unless it's iterating a collection of exactly 100 items. How many `<input name="valores"/>` elements are in the document?

Comment: It can be more than 100 or less, it's possible to use up to 200 <input name="valores"/>

Comment: Working example with 150 elements: https://jsfiddle.net/aey7notr/ -> Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: each loops don't just randomly stop. They stop when there's nothing left to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you it seems to be working perfectly the problem is that console log does not show more than 100 iterations.

When I print and alert it show me the last input value even if I add more than 200

:)